# Adding a column to a dataframe based on criteria in the row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, calculated-columns

I have a dataframe like this:

```
case    sex     is1     is5     is10    im1     im5     im10
686     m       0.1406  0.2997  0.1490  0.1339  0.1350  0.1417
950     f       0.1602  0.3448  0.1719  0.0884  0.0962  0.1385
1005    f       0.1641  0.2606  0.1507  0.1306  0.1613  0.1328
1005    m       0.1456  0.3097  0.1825  0.1116  0.1295  0.1211
```

I'd like to add a 9th column using a formula, say

```
if df['sex'] == 'm':
    df['new col']=const1*df['is1']+const2*df['is5']+.....+const6*df['im10']
else:
    df['new col'] = const7*df['is1']+.....const12*df['im10']
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['new col'] = np.where(df.sex=='m', 
                         df.drop(['case','sex'],1).dot(const_m), 
                         df.drop(['case','sex'],1).dot(const_f))
```

where `const_m` is a list of coefficients for `male` and `const_f` is a list of coefficients for `female`

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my question, because I found a way to *keep* the columns I need. All of them do begin with 'i'. Thanks again.

Comment: @DPdl, glad i could help! :) Alternatively we could use `df.filter(regex=r'^i[sm]\d+')`